# Connect external database in php

Tags: google-app-engine

I am beginner in php as well Google-app engine. I have created a php webpage, I just need this to connect to external MySQL database to log user visit stats.
Under `stats.php` how can I `include("config.php");` also in `config.php` how to connect:

```
<?php
// change these variables 
$host=("example.com");  //host
$uname="abc";//MySQL username
$pass="Abc@123";//MySQL password
$db="stats"; //MySQL Database
//don't need to change
$con = mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pass);
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db($db, $con);
?>
```

When I run `stats.php` I am getting below error on appspot.com

```
Failed to connect to MySQL: Unable to find the socket transport "tcp" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?
```

I have also confirmed connectivity to my server from outside host, `port 3306` is also opened.

```
$ mysql -u webadmin –h (server ip) –p
```

I am not getting proper way to use fetch url, 
please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately this won't work (yet).  The reason is that the App Engine PHP runtime doesn't currently support sockets.  Other App Engine runtimes (Python/Java/Go) support sockets, so it's a safe bet that it'll be added to PHP at some point in the future.

Comment: Sockets are now allowed for paid PHP projects in GAE (circa 2015). You must enable billing for your project, and then you'll be able to connect out. We have PHP apps in GAE that can talk to AWS services as well as externally-hosted MySQL servers.

Answer (score 0):

```
$host="example.com";     // should contain a valid host name or an ip address of the mysql server to which you want to connect
```

Nothing else needs to be changed, username and password  only if required different. You have to make sure that the remote database does allow external connections for that username. Besides, you'd be better off using `mysqli_*` instead of old deprecated `mysql_*` extension for MySQL.

```
$link = mysqli_connect($host,$uname,$pass,$db) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
```

And under stats.php you can simply include any code file the way you already mentioned:

```
<?php
include("config.php");
?>
```

Comment: I have added this webpage on appspot.com checked, and confirmed all database details are fine, which I am already using on my server, from Google App Engine I could not able to connect MySQL to my server, also confirmed from other host connectivity is reachable.

Comment: GAE does not allow connection to remote MySQL yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
$con = mysql_connect('your_my_sql_servername or IP Address', 'new_user_which_u_created', 'password');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

echo 'Connected successfully';

mysql_select_db('sandsbtob',$con) or die ("could not open db".mysql_error());
```

and also **firewall of the server must be set-up to enable incomming connections on port 3306**

Hope this will help you

Comment: Port 3306 is opened and working, checked by connecting to MySQL from other host, but from Google App Engine could not able to connect.

Comment: GAE does not allow connection to remote MySQL yet.